# How to include google map in angular2 - cordova hybrid app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, google-maps

Firstly, I tried google map using javascript code(here is the link for which i used - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial), it was working in Android but not in Ios, then tried including the cordova google map plugin, but it was not working in both. 
Can anyone tell that how to include the cordova google map plugin in the project or why the javascript code is not working in ios.